# Is the definite article missing in this sentence from Fox News?

Tags: articles, definite-article

A sentence on [Fox News](http://www.foxnews.com/health/2018/04/20/sick-dogs-cancer-revealed-to-be-chewed-up-teddy-bears.html) reads ungrammatical.

> Maisy, who bears similarities to **loveable pooch Beethoven** in the series of comedy films written by John Hughes, had the soft toys removed during an intricate procedure.

Is this a simple grammar error of missing the definite article? Since the dog is specified, I thought the correct sentence should be:

> Maisy, who bears similarities to **the loveable pooch Beethoven** in the series of comedy films written by John Hughes, had the soft toys removed during an intricate procedure.

Am I right?

Comment: This is actually a correct and idiomatic usage.  We do sometimes attach adjectives to proper names.  I'll see if I can find a reference to it.

Comment: I am somewhat stumped. *Lisa likes David* is fine. But *Lisa likes* ***the*** *David* sounds wrong. (Even though I could understand *Lisa likes* ***this*** *David* when used in a room full of people named David.) But when an adjective is added, the opposite seems to be the case. *Lisa likes* ***the lovely*** *David* sounds right. But *Lisa likes lovely David* sounds wrong. I haven't found a source that says if it's grammatical or not. But I would say that it's at least *awkward* to have not have an article before an adjective+name construction.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the only time I really hear an adjective+name construction is for something like *the honourable Judge Smith presiding*, so I'm simply used to the article in that situation and assume it as a rule for every case . . .

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing remotely "ungrammatical" about the cited usage (with or without a leading article). Google Books offers *some* support for OP's idea that the article "should" be present...

> 1: *[Something was done] **by well-known comedian** [comedian's name]* [(320 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=NiIEW_i4OMSTkwWVkZ2ABA&q=%22by%20well-known%20comedian%22&oq=%22by%20well-known%20comedian%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6674.7176.0.7528.4.4.0.0.0.0.75.267.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ffBQHhziUzs)
>    2: *[Something was done] **by the well-known comedian** [comedian's name]* [(1300 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=KSIEW7WFNIbksAf6iZ7YDQ&q=%22by%20the%20well-known%20comedian%22&oq=%22by%20the%20well-known%20comedian%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10871.12003.0.12299.4.4.0.0.0.0.93.334.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.O1-Hj5ddaHM)

...but you can't take that as implying there's anything *wrong* with the less common version. It just tells you what form people are *most* likely to use - which choice I don't think could ever affect the meaning anyway.

It's important to bear in mind that newspapers are primarily written for *native* speakers. The fact that some of the phrasing they use might be difficult for some learners wouldn't normally be a consideration.

On the other hand, I think it *is* true that some newspapers sometimes deliberately use relatively "exotic" syntax simply *because* they know this can have particular appeal for some readers (who perhaps take pride in the fact that they can understand "unusual" usages, and/or admire the linguistic skills of people who get paid to put them in print).

Answer (score -1):

I think the original is grammatical, although I’d agree that it reads a little bit odd.

I think the key is to rewrite the sentence without the word *pooch*:

> Maisy, who bears similarities to lovable Beethoven...

The problem with that, though, is some people might not realize Beethoven refers to a dog. So perhaps the writer decided to make that clear:

> Maisy, who bears similarities to lovable (pooch) Beethoven...

Once the parentheses are removed, you could indeed put the definite article in front of the clause, but I don’t think it’s “incorrect” to leave it out.

Comment: I don't think the problem here is *pooch* but *lovable*. I added more comments to the original question, but I think that even if dropping the article in front of the adjective is grammatical (I can't find a source either way), it's at least awkward.

Comment: @JasonB - You and I seem to agree that it’s sloppy journalism.